How do I read a csv dataset on python?
I have tried to read a csv dataset on python in jupyter notebooks using the pandas library but I come back with a message saying I do not have the right file or directory name.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np`





path = '/Users/alfielenton/Documents/MonthlyGlobalTemp.csv'
df=pd.read_csv('/Users/alfielenton/Documents/MonthlyGlobalTemp.csv')

And this is the error I am getting, what am I doing wrong?
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
\<ipython-input-2-fe82d903835c\> in \<cell line: 2\>()
1 path = '/Users/alfielenton/Documents/MonthlyGlobalTemp.csv'
\----\> 2 df = pd.read_csv('/Users/alfielenton/Documents/MonthlyGlobalTemp.csv')

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode,           encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
857         if ioargs.encoding and "b" not in ioargs.mode:
858             # Encoding
\--\> 859             handle = open(
860                 handle,
861                 ioargs.mode,

FileNotFoundError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory:        '/Users/alfielenton/Documents/MonthlyGlobalTemp.csv'


Make sure the path is correct:import os print(os.path.exists('/Users/alfielenton/Documents/MonthlyGlobalTemp.csv'))

Does this answer your question? How to resolve FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: in Pandas?

how do I find the proper path of my file then? This is the path I can see

No chance OneDrive is involved is here? If not, then explore from within running Jupyter using %cd and ls and pwd to demonstrate to yourself and us (by updating your post with the results and commenting you did) to demonstrate if this is the case. As stated in How do I ask a good question?, you want to show us the "circumstances that make your question different from similar questions already on the site."

Best option is to put the .csv file that you want to read in the subfolder of the folder where your python script is. Then you can use following command to get path to your current folder path = os.getcwd() (before you need to import os module in your script import os). Here is the script that should work:
import os
import pandas as pd

path = os.getcwd()
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, 'Input', 'MonthlyGlobalTemp.csv'))

Where 'Input' is the name of the subfodler where you have put your .csv file
